# SQL, how do I create a flight sector route

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate all the sales on the sector level (1 sector is 2 legs, round trip).

Flight Leg Info

```
Leg Key, FlightNumber, DepAirport, DestAirport, DepDate, SectorSerial, LegSerial
2222, 1234, AMS,BCN,20201020,1,1
2223, 1235, BCN,AMS,20201020,1,2
2224, 1236, AMS,CDG,20201020,1,1
2225, 1237, CDG,AMS,20201020,1,2
```

Sales

```
TransactionKey,SectorSerial,LegKey,Amount
122,1,2222,2.5
123,1,2222,3
124,1,2224,5
125,1,2225,6
126,1,2223,8
```

What I want to have is like this

```
FlightNumber, Route,DepDate,Sales
1234, AMS-BCN-AMS,20201020,5.5
```

Any helps would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in the type of database because syntax could be different.
Assuming a non-Microsoft Access database, you need a recursive CTE to get this done. This should get your started:

```
With SalesSummary as
(
 select LegKey,SectorSerial, Sum(Amount) as Sales
from Sales
Group by LegKey, SectorSerial
), FlightTrip(FlightNumber, LegKey, DestAirport, Route, DepDate, SectorSerial, LegSerial) AS   
(  
    SELECT FlightNumber, LegKey, DestAirport, CAST(DepAirport + '-' + DestAirport AS VARCHAR(MAX)), DepDate, SectorSerial, LegSerial  
    FROM FlightLegInfo where LegSerial = 1   
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT d.FlightNumber, d.LegKey, e.DestAirport, (d.Route + '-' + e.DestAirport), d.DepDate, d.SectorSerial, e.LegSerial  
    FROM FlightLegInfo e INNER JOIN FlightTrip d  
        ON e.DepAirport = d.DestAirport and e.SectorSerial=d.SectorSerial
        and e.LegSerial=d.LegSerial+1 and e.flightnumber>d.flightnumber
 )
SELECT FlightNumber, Route, DepDate, ss.Sales   
FROM FlightTrip ft inner join SalesSummary ss 
on ft.LegKey = ss.LegKey and ft.SectorSerial=ss.SectorSerial and ft.LegSerial=2
```

The solution above is a simple solution to handle your exact case of max legkey=2. You can find the sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/54d17/26

I did wonder how this would work with a third leg of the trip to become more dynamic and I came upon another solution which is really your real solution for any number legs for a flight trip. You can find it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76643/1

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am new to recursive CTE. I have tried the code for FightTrip part. The result I got has duplicate flightnumbers and Legkeys. I found out there is no DestAirport, Legkey Columns in the FlightTrip CTE, I added that. Also I added one join e.LegSerial = d.LegSerial+1.

Comment: Glad you were able to understand it to make your own changes. Yes. That’s what a recursive cte does. It starts with a parent and drills down to child rows. At the end, you will see the parent, and all the children in the data. In the final query, you can filter out the child row you need. Recursive CTEs are useful in navigating parent child hierarchies like employee-manager relationships or your example.

Comment: I have one last puzzle. Sector Serial and Leg Serial can be something like this: 1,1; 1,2; 2,3; 2,4. So I can get all the data fro the sector 1, but the sector afterwards are not there. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I thought the sql fiddle I left already did that - especially the second fiddle that's more dynamic. I think you would need to show how that output would be different from what you already presented.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried on sqlfiddle and figure it out. Not ideal though but it is working.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38b92/18